# How to Aggregate and get group count in specific column from text file by perl?

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a big text file(with 15 lines) in this format (srip dip sport dport .....)
I would like to group distinct first column and get the group counts,

input file:

```
10.10.10.1 10.10.66.150 60761 502 2019-02-28 13:30:31.447 0 6 ....S. 0 1 44 1 cluster1
10.10.10.1 10.10.66.150 60761 502 2019-02-28 13:30:31.447 0 6 ....S. 0 1 44 1 cluster1
10.10.10.3 10.10.66.150 60761 502 2019-02-28 13:30:31.447 0 6 ....S. 0 1 44 1 cluster1
10.10.10.4 10.10.66.150 60761 502 2019-02-28 13:30:31.447 0 6 ....S. 0 1 44 1 cluster1
```

I want to get output file sort by counts like  as below,

```
10.10.10.1 2
10.10.10.3 1
10.10.10.4 1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet can be used to serve the desired purpose

```
use strict
use warnings

my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<', $filename)  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my %count;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my @words = split(' ', $line);
    my $ip = $words[0];
    $count{$ip}++;
}

while (my ($k,$v)=each %count){
    print "$k $v\n"
}
```

**Explanation**

- Open the file for reading

```
my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<', $filename)  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
```

- Iterate over lines of file and find words by splitting the line on space. Extract the first column value from each line and store it in a hash, with the column as key and value as number of occurrence of key

```
my %count;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my @words = split(' ', $line);
    my $ip = $words[0];
    $count{$ip}++;
}
```

> Note hash has following structure **{ "key" : "value" }**
>     Here hash will contain the values as:
>           
>           `{
>             '10.10.10.1' => 2,
>             '10.10.10.3' => 1,
>             '10.10.10.4' => 1
>           }`

- Finally iterate over key, value pairs in count hash and print the key i.e column and value i.e count

```
foreach my $key (sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count) {
    print "$key $count{$key}\n"
}
```

- Here `sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} }` is for descending order sort on hash values
- Use `sort { $count{$a} <=> $count{$b} }` for ascending order sort on hash values
- Use `sort { $a <=> $b }` for ascending order sort on hash keys
- Use `sort {$b <=> $a}` for descending order sort on hash keys

Comment: how to sort by count  ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a sort function on values for descending order

Comment: thanks, but it's only print counts sort results ,didnt print ip ? It's possible to print ip  and count and sort by count ?

Comment: It must be printing both ip and count `print "$key $count{$key}\n"`, here $key is ip and $count{$key} is count, can you check again ?

Comment: Can you paste the output as well, what it is returning

Comment: as you said ,the output can print ip and count ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simplicity:

```
cat [*filename*] | cut -f 1 -d \“ \“ | sort -n | uniq -c
```

F.

Comment: This doesn’t count the occurrences... Please avoid smart quotes in code too, it means readers can’t copy and paste.

Comment: Alas, did I forget the ‘-c’ appendage?  No worries, I edit my answer...

Comment: Your quotes are still messed up ;-)